# Selecting from Python lists using values rather than indices

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a tuple:

```
aList = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
```

I know that I can select a subset from that based on indices using:

```
list(aList[i] for i in [ 1, 5, 6 ] )
```

which would produce

```
['b', 'f', 'g']
```

My question is, can I select a subset of items from a list based on the *value* rather than the index?  If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
[v for v in aList if v in ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

BTW, `aList` there is a tuple, not a list. List would be between brackets.

Just for a list of characters, you can also do:

```
[v for v in aList if v in 'def']
```

Comment: suggestion: `... if v in 'def'`

Comment: @timgeb Works for list of characters.

Comment: Of course it does, I'd just argue that the other version is easier to read.

Comment: @timgeb I would agree on that.

Comment: Whoops... @RohitJain  List, Tuple... :)  You know what I meant. :)  I edited the question to clarify.  Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x in ['b','f','g'], aList))
```